# How to handle Custom Events of Tabs on TabNavigator ReactNative?

Tags: react-native

I am taking a bottom tab navigator which is having five screens. At third screen which is home screen I want to open modal which contain 2 buttons. When user click on home button show modal and hide tab navigator and when user click anywhere at screen it gets out from modal .

I want functionality like this issue on GitHub presented :
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1059.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle click on tab using next https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOnPress

So in tabBarOnPress you can implement your custom logic ( open modal, trigger redux action, etc... )

Comment: link is broken.